# Copying Information From One Table to Another in Same Database With Shared ID?

Tags: mysql

Good Morning All

I have been researching the forums this morning but haven't been able to answer my question.

I am trying to extract all the data from one table into another in the same database using phpmyadmin.

The information is pulled together and used for one 'id' but I want to have all the information in one table. This is so that I can easily export the information into a csv file.

It seems like I can possibly move or export the information.

However, my main question is this.

I need the system to realise that information from the two tables for the same ID needs to be merged together with only one id remaining. The only shared information in the two tables is the ID?

Would somebody be able to point me in the right direction as to how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Just to add the table structure.

Table 1 : -

Table structure for table jos_cck_store_form_delegate

Column
Type
Null
Default
id
int(11)
No

delegate_title
varchar(255)
No

delegate_first_name
varchar(255)
No

delegate_last_name
varchar(255)
No

delegate_institution
varchar(255)
No

delegate_role
varchar(255)
No

delegate_email
varchar(255)
No

delegate_email_copy
varchar(255)
No

delegate_phone
varchar(255)
No

delegate_address
text
No

delegate_partner
varchar(255)
No

delegate_diet
varchar(255)
No

delegate_access
varchar(255)
No

delegate_bio
varchar(255)
No

title
varchar(255)
No

delegate_tests
varchar(255)
No

delegate_postal_address
text
No

delegate_delivery_telephone
varchar(255)
No

delegate_wednesday_accom
varchar(255)
No

delegate_thursday_accomodation
varchar(255)
No

delegate_friday_accomodation
varchar(255)
No

delegate_saturday_accomodation
varchar(255)
No

delegate_sunday_accomodation
varchar(255)
No

delegate_accomodation_notes
text
No

delegate_meal_requirements
varchar(255)
No

delegate_wednesday_dinner
varchar(255)
No

delegate_thursday_breakfast
varchar(255)
No

delegate_thursday_lunch
varchar(255)
No

delegate_thursday_dinner
varchar(255)
No

delegate_friday_breakfast
varchar(255)
No

delegate_friday_lunch
varchar(255)
No

delegate_friday_dinner
varchar(255)
No

delegate_saturday_breakfast
varchar(255)
No

delegate_saturday_lunch
varchar(255)
No

delegate_saturday_dinner
varchar(255)
No

delegate_sunday_breakfast
varchar(255)
No

delegate_sunday_lunch
varchar(255)
No

delegate_sunday_dinner
varchar(255)
No

delegate_monday_breakfast
varchar(255)
No

delegate_travel
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_arrival
varchar(255)
No

delegate_arrival_flight_number
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_arrival_time
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_origin
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_arrival_airport_and_terminal
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_pickup
varchar(255)
No

delegate_arrival_car_address
varchar(255)
No

delegate_arrival_train_station
varchar(255)
No

delegate_arrival_train_time
varchar(255)
No

delegate_arrival_train_station_of_origin
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_pickup_address_thursday
text
No

delegate_car_pickup_time_thursday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_pickup_address_friday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_pickup_time_friday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_pickup_address_saturday
text
No

delegate_car_pickup_time_saturday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_pickup_address_sunday
text
No

delegate_car_pickup_time_sunday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_parking_arrival_time
varchar(255)
No

delegate_car_parking_days
varchar(255)
No

delegate_parking_thursday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_parking_friday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_parking_saturday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_parking_sunday
varchar(255)
No

delegate_photo
varchar(255)
No

Table 2
Table structure for table jos_cck_store_item_content

Column
Type
Null
Default
id
int(11)
No

cck
varchar(50)
No

delegate_first_name
varchar(255)
No

delegate_test
varchar(255)
No

delegate_accomodation
varchar(255)
No

delegate_train_car_pickup_time
varchar(255)
No

delegate_train_car_pickup_address
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_departure_airline
varchar(255)
No

delegate_departure_flight_number
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_departure_time
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_departure_airport_and_terminal
varchar(255)
No

delgates_departure_destination_airport
varchar(255)
No

delegate_departure_train_station
varchar(255)
No

delegate_train_departure_time
varchar(255)
No

departure_destination_train_station
varchar(255)
No

delegate_train_departure_pickup_address
varchar(255)
No

delegate_flight_departure_pickup_address
text
No

delegate_bio
text
No

introtext
text
No

Comment: Your query seems pretty straight. But it would also be good to show sample structures of both the tables and their columns.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly ravinder. I can perform the basic functions of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Please post structure of your database tables.

Comment: What are your table structures, and how exactly do you want the information to be “merged” …?

Comment: Sorry posted too early. The tables basically contain user information which has been split up. so for example, one person will have a row in each table. As a classic example, first name is on one table and last name is in another.

Comment: So I would like there to be just one table that shows all the information related to each person. At the moment the information is split over two tables and connected together with the same id.

Comment: If you need more information just let me know

Comment: You probably need some kind of JOIN query - we can help with this, but you need to paste the structure of your tables into the question so that we know what the tables and fields are called.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone, I've just added the table structures to my original comment as there weren't enough characters available in the comments. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Morning All (UK Time). I've been reading up on join statements? I'm not sure if this will be solution. I need to make the content be in one physical table, and then when that has been achieved i need to change the order or structure of the columns. Would a join query work here? Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of fields. If you run this SQL does it return the expected data? 

`SELECT
 jos_cck_store_form_delegate.*,
 jos_cck_store_item_content.*
FROM
 jos_cck_store_form_delegate
INNER JOIN
 jos_cck_store_item_content
ON
 jos_cck_store_item_content.id = jos_cck_store_form_delegate.id
;`

Comment: If that returns the correct data - you can then create a table from it like this - `CREATE TABLE newTable (SELECT
 jos_cck_store_form_delegate.*,
 jos_cck_store_item_content.*
FROM
 jos_cck_store_form_delegate
INNER JOIN
 jos_cck_store_item_content
ON
 jos_cck_store_item_content.id = jos_cck_store_form_delegate.id
);`

Comment: Thank you very much madebydavid. I think we must be almost there but there is just one last problem. The first query returned all the information as expected but displayed both ID's. The second query then bought up the following error message? ' #1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'. Is there a small tweak to the query that needs to be made? Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL to create a new table from the existing data (joined) - the table is called "newTable" you can change this name to be whatever you need. You should be able to see we are specifying each column we want in the output and the order - you can change this as you need. If you are doing a lot of fiddling with the data and it is "fixed" ie new records are not being added all the time, then it might be best to export this data into a spreadsheet and play around with it there. Here comes a huge bit of code:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable (
    SELECT 
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.id,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_title,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_first_name,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_last_name,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_institution,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_role,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_email,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_email_copy,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_phone,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_address,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_partner,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_diet,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_access,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_bio,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.title,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_tests,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_postal_address,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_delivery_telephone,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_wednesday_accom,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_thursday_accomodation,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_friday_accomodation,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_saturday_accomodation,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_sunday_accomodation,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_accomodation_notes,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_meal_requirements,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_wednesday_dinner,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_thursday_breakfast,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_thursday_lunch,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_thursday_dinner,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_friday_breakfast,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_friday_lunch,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_friday_dinner,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_saturday_breakfast,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_saturday_lunch,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_saturday_dinner,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_sunday_breakfast,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_sunday_lunch,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_sunday_dinner,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_monday_breakfast,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_travel,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_flight_arrival,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_arrival_flight_number,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_flight_arrival_time,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_flight_origin,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_flight_arrival_airport_and_terminal,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_arrival_car_address,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_arrival_train_station,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_arrival_train_time,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_arrival_train_station_of_origin,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_address_thursday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_time_thursday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_address_friday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_time_friday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_address_saturday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_time_saturday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_address_sunday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_pickup_time_sunday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_parking_arrival_time,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_car_parking_days,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_parking_thursday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_parking_friday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_parking_saturday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_parking_sunday,
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate.delegate_photo,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.cck,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_test,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_accomodation,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_train_car_pickup_time,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_train_car_pickup_address,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_flight_departure_airline,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_departure_flight_number,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_flight_departure_time,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_flight_departure_airport_and_terminal,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delgates_departure_destination_airport,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_departure_train_station,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_train_departure_time,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.departure_destination_train_station,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_train_departure_pickup_address,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_flight_departure_pickup_address,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.delegate_bio AS delegate_bio_2,
        jos_cck_store_item_content.introtext
    FROM 
        jos_cck_store_form_delegate 
    INNER JOIN 
        jos_cck_store_item_content 
    ON 
        jos_cck_store_item_content.id = jos_cck_store_form_delegate.id 
);
```

Comment: Hello madebyDavid. First of all, sorry for the delay in response, I've just got a new computer and have been setting that up. I have just tried that code and it has worked perfectly, thank you for all of your time and effort, especially with the amount of fields involved. Is there a way that i can officially thank you on this forum?

Comment: Hi @user3045451 - no problem - you can accept my answer if you are happy with it. To do this, click the ✔ sign next to my answer - this page shows how http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235